# Assing integer value to image with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am new to iOS **Sprite Kit** and trying to create a game with numbers.

Is it possible to assign an integer value to the image so that when I touch an image `1`, I will see the value on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need you would have to create a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and change its **texture** or `UIImageView` and change its **image** based on the number.

1. **Create** your own subclass of `UIImageView` or `SKSpriteNode`.

   ```
   @interface NumberImageView : UIImageView
   @end

   or

   @interface NumberSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode
   @end
   ```
2. **Create a property** to store number

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger number;
   ```
3. Implement the `touchesEnded:` method to **handle the tap** event.

   ```
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
       [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

       if (touch.tapCount == 1)
       {
           [self setImageForCurrentNumber];
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Set the image** based on number value.

   ```
   - (void)setImageForCurrentNumber
   {
       switch (_number)
       {
           case 1:
               self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1"];
               break;

           case 2:
               self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2"];
               break;

           default:
               self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

You also need to set the **`userInteractionEnabled`** property of your `UIImageView` or `SKSpriteNode` to `YES` so they can detect touch events. You can do it in the `init` method.

Example:

```
- (void)commonInit
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }

    return self;
}
```